# MongoDB aggregation pipeline filtering two arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Could you give me advise? I have a document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("569620270d3ac01895316edb"),
    "customerId" : NumberLong("2000900000000000022"),
    "gender" : "MALE",
    "birthDate" : ISODate("1976-01-06T23:00:00Z"),
    "someArray" : [
            {
                    "id" : 5411,
                    "firstDate" : ISODate("2014-08-05T16:17:50Z"),
                    "lastDate" : ISODate("2015-10-31T11:55:51Z"),
                    "sumOfAll" : 5677.35,
                    "minAmount" : 9.75,
                    "maxAmount" : 231.72,
                    "innerArray" : [
                            {
                                    "count" : 4,
                                    "amount" : 449.33
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 3,
                                    "amount" : 401.31
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 7,
                                    "amount" : 617.8000000000001
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 4,
                                    "amount" : 465.28999999999996
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 2,
                                    "amount" : 212.95999999999998
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 4,
                                    "amount" : 497.53999999999996
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 3,
                                    "amount" : 278.23
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 3,
                                    "amount" : 383.15999999999997
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 6,
                                    "amount" : 459.63
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 9,
                                    "amount" : 677.19
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 4,
                                    "amount" : 393.85
                            }
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "id" : 5812,
                    "firstDate" : ISODate("2014-09-03T17:16:32Z"),
                    "lastDate" : ISODate("2015-11-04T22:59:59Z"),
                    "sumOfAll" : 275.6,
                    "minAmount" : 15,
                    "maxAmount" : 69,
                    "innerArray" : [
                            {
                                    "count" : 1,
                                    "amount" : 17
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 1,
                                    "amount" : 15.4
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 1,
                                    "amount" : 69
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 1,
                                    "amount" : 53.7
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 2,
                                    "amount" : 84
                            }
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "id" : 7399,
                    "firstDate" : ISODate("2015-01-12T22:59:59Z"),
                    "lastDate" : ISODate("2015-03-16T22:59:59Z"),
                    "sumOfAll" : 144.73,
                    "minAmount" : 0.84,
                    "maxAmount" : 24.98,
                    "innerArray" : [
                            {
                                    "count" : 5,
                                    "amount" : 50.379999999999995
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 5,
                                    "amount" : 55.45
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 10,
                                    "amount" : 38.900000000000006
                            }
                    ]
            },
    ]
```

}

And I'd like to filter both inner arrays and also project them. I'm trying this query:

```
db.sandbox.aggregate([
{ $match: {
           'gender': {$eq : 'MALE'},
           $or: [
                { $and: [{'someArray.id': {$eq: 5411}}, {'someArray.innerArray.count': 4}, {'someArray.innerArray.amount': {$gte: 2}}]},
                { $and: [{'someArray.id': {$eq: 5812}}, {'someArray.innerArray.count': 5}, {'someArray.innerArray.amount': {$gte: 50}}]},
           ]
          }
},
{ $project: {
    gender: 1,
    customerId: 1,
    someArray: { $filter: {
        input: '$someArray',
        as: 'item',
        cond: {
        $and: [ 
            { $or: [
                {$and: [{$eq: ['$$item.id', 5411]}, {$eq: ['$$item.innerArray.count', 4]}, {$gte: ['$$item.innerArray.amount', 2]}]},
                {$and: [{$eq: ['$$item.id', 5812]}, {$eq: ['$$item.innerArray.count', 5]}, {$gte: ['$$item.innerArray.amount', 50]}]},
            ]},
        ]
      }
    }},
}}
```

]).pretty()

And I received result without data in someArray:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("569620270d3ac01895316edb"),
    "customerId" : NumberLong("2000900000000000022"),
    "gender" : "MALE",
    "someArray" : [ ]
```

}

I want to receive:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("569620270d3ac01895316edb"),
    "customerId" : NumberLong("2000900000000000022"),
    "gender" : "MALE",
    "birthDate" : ISODate("1976-01-06T23:00:00Z"),
    "someArray" : [
            {
                    "id" : 5411,
                    "firstDate" : ISODate("2014-08-05T16:17:50Z"),
                    "lastDate" : ISODate("2015-10-31T11:55:51Z"),
                    "sumOfAll" : 5677.35,
                    "minAmount" : 9.75,
                    "maxAmount" : 231.72,
                    "innerArray" : [
                            {
                                    "count" : 4,
                                    "amount" : 449.33
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 4,
                                    "amount" : 465.28999999999996
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 4,
                                    "amount" : 497.53999999999996
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 4,
                                    "amount" : 393.85
                            }
                    ]
            }
    ]
```

}

If I change $eq to $gte, I will receive receive result, but I want to project innerArray too. How can I implement this? Should I use my own MapReduce job or I will able to do this with Aggregation pipeline?

MongoDB version 3.2. Also I observe when I'm trying to use several predicates for array and project only one element, for example:

```
db.sandbox.find(  {$and: [{'someArray.id': 7399}, {'someArray.sumOfAll': {$gte: 5000}}]}, {'customerId': 1, 'someArray.$': 1}).pretty()
```

But it returns me:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("569620270d3ac01895316edb"),
    "customerId" : NumberLong("2000900000000000022"),
    "someArray" : [
            {
                    "id" : 5411,
                    "firstDate" : ISODate("2014-08-05T16:17:50Z"),
                    "lastDate" : ISODate("2015-10-31T11:55:51Z"),
                    "sumOfAll" : 5677.35,
                    "minAmount" : 9.75,
                    "maxAmount" : 231.72,
                    "innerArray" : [
                            {
                                    "count" : 4,
                                    "amount" : 449.33
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 3,
                                    "amount" : 401.31
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 7,
                                    "amount" : 617.8000000000001
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 4,
                                    "amount" : 465.28999999999996
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 2,
                                    "amount" : 212.95999999999998
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 4,
                                    "amount" : 497.53999999999996
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 3,
                                    "amount" : 278.23
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 3,
                                    "amount" : 383.15999999999997
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 6,
                                    "amount" : 459.63
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 9,
                                    "amount" : 677.19
                            },
                            {
                                    "count" : 4,
                                    "amount" : 393.85
                            }
                    ]
            }
    ]
```

}

Which is incorrect for my perspective. I expect nothing.

Comment: Could you please describe what you are trying to achieve, in writing instead of as a query?

Comment: I think second part shows exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why do you expect a `someArray` element with `"sumOfAll" : 144.73` in the result of your second query? You specified that this field should be greater or equal to 5000 in the query.

Comment: OK, you are giving too many queries that are not working in a single question. Which one do you want us to help you with? Or which general problem?

Comment: Sorry about this. General problem is - I want to filter both array simultaneously based on some predicates and I want to project result based on these predicates.

Comment: What are your expected results for these queries?

Comment: I've added expected result for aggregation and for last one I expect nothing

Answer (score 0):

First, the way you're using conditions in `$match` will not result in what you want.

```
{ $and: [{'someArray.id': {$eq: 5411}}, {'someArray.innerArray.count': 4}, {'someArray.innerArray.amount': {$gte: 2}}]}
```

The line above will verify each condition separately, instead of checking the `count` and `amount` conditions together for each `innerArray` element. If that's what you want, you should look into the [**`$elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) operator.

Second, I don't believe you can use `$filter` like that on a second-level array. You should unwind `someArray` first:

```js
db.sandbox.aggregate(
{
    $match:
    {
        gender: { $eq: 'MALE' },
        "someArray.id":
        {
            $in: [5411, 5812]
        }
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$someArray",
},
{
    $project:
    {
        gender: 1,
        customerId: 1,
        someArray:
        {
            id: 1,
            firstDate: 1,
            lastDate: 1,
            sumOfAll: 1,
            minAmount: 1,
            maxAmount: 1,
            innerArray:
            {
                $filter:
                {
                    input: '$someArray.innerArray',
                    as: 'item',
                    cond:
                    {
                        $or:
                        [
                            {
                                $and:
                                [
                                    { $eq: ['$$item.count', 4] },
                                    { $gte: ['$$item.amount', 2] }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                $and:
                                [
                                    { $eq: ['$$item.count', 5] },
                                    { $gte: ['$$item.amount', 50] }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    }
})
```

You can also [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) `someArray` elements back if you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
For first I used [$(projection)](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) but I didn't look at the condition limitations, so I need to switch to elemMatch in this case.
For second issue query looks really ugly, might be I need to change my  document schema to work better with.

Comment: Here is necessary another one match, after unwind or you will get redundant results.

Comment: If it possible, without match after unwind your code can return irrelevance answer. To get right answer I've added 
`{
    $match:
    {
        "someArray.id":
        {
            $in: [7011,5812,5411,5651,6011,5542,5691]
        }
    }
}` 
between unwind and projection